# Cannot deploy program on mainnet for two weeks

Tags: program, deploy, mainnet

I use solana command tool to deploy program on mainnet and always got failed. I have try for two weeks.
I try 1.14.X, 1.16.X and 1.17.X. But got failed.

```
tangaoyuan@tangaoyuandeMacBook-Pro program % solana program deploy --buffer ~/.config/solana/id.json --program-id ~/.config/solana/cli/contract1.json ./target/deploy/solana_market.so
Blockhash expired. 4 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 3 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 2 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 1 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 0 retries remaining
Error: Data writes to account failed: Custom error: Max retries exceeded
```

The network traffic is so big recently and can not deploy program on mainnet any more?
Does anyone deploy program on mainnet successfully last two weeks?

What should I do？

Comment: Maybe it's a little slow, but it works on my side. Do devnet and testnet work? If not, then there might be a problem with your connection